# Reading from a FILE; cannot create process

Tags: c, file-io

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("text.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL)
        printf("ahaha");

    struct karan{
        int index;
        int number;
        char string[10];
    };

    struct karan first;

    fscanf(fp,"%d %d %s",first.index,first.number,first.string);
    printf("%d %d %s",first.index,first.number,first.string);
}
```

If my text file contains

1 123 karan
2 1234 haha

When i compile the code it says
Possible use of first before definition.

and on running the code it says
Cannot create process!
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably put your `struct` definition outside of `main` (perhaps in a header). It shouldn't be a problem, but do it anyway. It looks nicer, and you may want to use that `struct` somewhere else as well.

Comment: Also, `void main()` is rarely (though sometimes) a good idea. Use `int main()`, and `return 0;` if your program was successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `&` operator with `fscanf`.

```
fscanf(fp,"%d %d %s",first.index,first.number,first.string); /* Wrong. */
fscanf(fp,"%d %d %9s", &first.index, &first.number, first.string); /* Right. */
                  ^
```

Otherwise you'll be treating the junk in `first` as addresses and will incur undefined behavior. Also, do note the format for `first.string`.

There is a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html)

> Why doesn't the call scanf("%d", i) work?
>
> The arguments you pass to scanf **must always be pointers**: for each
>   value converted, scanf ``returns'' it by filling in one of the
>   locations you've passed pointers to.

Comment: OHH! that should not have happened.Anyways, if i want to read the data from a file, is this the right way o doing it?

Comment: if my data is of different datatype!

Comment: @Karan Well, it's one way of doing it. Sometimes you might prefer to use `fgets` + `strtok` / `sscanf` / etc.

Comment: @Karan - Maybe? If you want robust error handling, `scanf` is very difficult to get right. If you can guarantee that the file is in the right format (and all the error handling you want is `if(fscanf(...) != 3) { fprintf(stderr, "WTF?\n"); exit(1); }` then it should be okay.

Comment: @cnicutar You don't need an `&` for `first.string`, the `char[10]` is converted to `char *`. You're actually passing it as a `char (*)[10]` (which is the same address and works, but is the wrong type). Also note that `*scanf` isn't checking the bounds for that argument, and that `%s` will only read in a word (not, say, an entire line), so if the data has spaces, `first.string` won't be what you want it to be.

Comment: @Chris Lutz I had already edited the format specifier for the string (missed it at first). Thanks for the heads up about the superfluous `&` :-)

Comment: @cnicutar    why does the following code doesnt create proces for me?
void main()  
{  
FILE *fp;  
fp=fopen("text.txt","r");  
if(fp==NULL)  
printf("ahaha");  
struct karan{  
int index;  
int number;  
char string[10];  
};  
struct karan first;  
char ch;  
ch=fgetc(fp);  
fscanf(fp,"%d %d %s",&first.index,&first.number,&first.string);  
printf("%d %d %s",first.index,first.number,first.string);  
}

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd personally use `fgets`, then `strtol` to read the numbers, then handle whatever's left. It's longer, but it's easier to understand what's going on than the (sometimes overly) complicated `scanf` codes, and easier to adapt if you change `.string` from a `char[10]` to a `char *`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz howcome if iwrite & with `first.string` it still gives me the write answer?

Comment: @Chris Lutz I myself rarely use `[f]scanf`, but it's good for quick and dirty tasks. Especially dirty.

Comment: @cnicutar could not create process.. IF the changes i made in the code are not visible to you, they are: char ch; and then ch=fgetc(fp); befor fscnaf;